# Como realizar contagem especifica de postagens personalizadas no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Ola gostaria da ajuda de vocês para o seguinte problema, eu gostaria de saber como posso realizar a contagem das postagens do WordPress, utilizando as configurações impostas no código abaixo, para realizar a contagem apenas de postagens com `meta_key` , `tipo_de_item` valor `Novo`, com parâmetro de postagem `publish`.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: DT - Revistas
*/
get_header();
doo_glossary('listagem');
global $user_ID;
$dt = isset( $_GET['get'] ) ? $_GET['get'] : null;
$admin = isset( $_GET['admin'] ) ? $_GET['admin'] : null;
echo '<div class="module"><div class="content">';
get_template_part('inc/parts/modules/featured-post-tvshows');
echo '<header><h1>'. __d('Novas'). '</h1></header>';
echo '<div id="archive-content" class="animation-2 items">';
// Ordenar em ordem alfabetica
global $wp_query;
$pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
query_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => $pages,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type'     => array('revista'),
    'meta_key'      => 'tipo_de_item',
    'meta_value'    => 'Novo',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'title'
));
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('inc/parts/item');
    }
}
echo '</div>';
if ( function_exists("pagination") ) {
    pagination();
}
echo '</div>';
get_template_part('inc/parts/sidebar');
echo '</div>';
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você disse "contar", por exemplo "10 posts"
Resposta:
Adicione esse trecho na seguinte linha de código:
Está assim:

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('inc/parts/item');
    }
}
```

Ficará Assim:

```
if (have_posts()) {
echo $wp_query->found_posts.' Posts'; // Exibe 'x' Posts
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('inc/parts/item');
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada peala resposta contudo, eu esqueci de mencionar que a contagem deve conseguir calcular todos os itens existentes, nesse caso, a função que você passou só conta o numero de itens por pagina. Eu preciso no caso que conte todos os itens existentes com esse parâmetros contidos  no banco de dados.

Comment: Poderia testar trocar o 'post_count' por found_posts ?

Comment: Pode classificar a minha resposta? xD é só clicar na setinha pra cima s2 Eu agradeço se puder. haha xD
E você está usando o dooplay ou algum tema da Doo, né? xD

Comment: Sim, você saberia me informar como posso ativar o modo Letter ? Fiz uma pergunta sobre isso mais não obitive resposta ainda.

Comment: É que suas perguntas não são muito claras cara kkkk
Mas eu sei informar sim, vou responder lá no tópico

Comment: Me desculpe, e que não sei muito os termos técnicos.